# Ruby + Bundler: using versionomy in lib/<gem>/version.rb

Tags: ruby, bundler, versioning

I use Versionomy for my gems, but it causes a problem for bundler when it tries to run the gemspec through its abbreviated include-path:

```
$ bundle check
There was a LoadError while loading envgraph.gemspec: 
cannot load such file -- versionomy from
  /home/coar/rhgit/redhat-git-utils/envgraph/envgraph.gemspec:9:in `<main>`
Does it try to require a relative path? That's been removed in Ruby 1.9.
```

By the time Bundler starts processing the gemspec, it has already set up its first pass at the include path -- which doesn't happen to encompass `versionomy.rb`'s location.

I've tried to inject the gem's location into the process in various ways, but Bundler insists on the gemspec being parsed with minimal context.

How can I persuade Bundler to stop mucking about with the include path until it's **asked** to with a `setup` method invocation?

Thanks..

Comment: I had a similar error with a different gem, that was related to having read/write permissions on the folder and it's contents.

Comment: I definitely have all access to the tree, so I don't think that was it.  This is a Catch-22 when you ask Bundler to get its dependencies from the gemspec, and the gemspec includes your app's `version.rb` file, and the `version.rb` file requires a gem.

I don't have an answer for this; my workaround has been to:

1. Hard-code a version in the gemspec;
2. Run bundler to build the `Gemfile.lock`;
3. Put the reference to the `version.rb`'s VERSION definition (from `Versionomy`) *back* into the gemspec.

From then on Bundler no longer complains.